# Which elements in a matrix are greater than x

Tags: r

I have a very simple question. I have a matrix y( 1 2 3 ) and want to access elements which are greater than 1. I do not aim to count them but want to get outputs which are 2 and 3

Comment: `y <- matrix(1:3); y[y > 1]`

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this:

```
A = matrix( 
c(1, 2, 3),     # the data elements 
nrow=1,         # number of rows 
ncol=3,         # number of columns 
byrow = TRUE)  

A

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   1    2    3
```

Greater than 1 :

```
which(A > 1)
```

which returns:

```
[1] 2 3
```

This will return values:

```
 A[A>1]
```

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: `which(A > 1)` returns the indices, not the values. In this example, they are identical.

Comment: yes, i agree. i forgot the add the last lines. just did it. thanks for reminding.

Comment: @Sena If this is the answer, please hit the "accept answer" button.